# Completing a proof that $\ell ^2 $ space is complete (a Hilbert space)

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

In my functional analysis textbook, there is a beginning of a proof that the inner product space $\ell ^ 2$ of square summable complex sequences is complete. Here is the beginning of the proof:

> Let $\{x^j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ be a Cauchy sequence of sequences in $\ell ^ 2$, i.e. for every $ j \in \mathbb{N} $ we have a sequence $\{x^j_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in \ell^2$ (which just means $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x^j_n|^2 <\infty$). Since the sequence $\{x^j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy, for any $ \epsilon > 0 $ there is a $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all natural $j,k > K$ one has: $$\big\|x^j - x^k \big\|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x^j_n - x^k_n |^2 < \epsilon $$ and hence $ |x^j_n - x^k_n |^2 < \epsilon $ for any $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ so that for fixed $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ the sequence $\{x^j_n\}_{j=1}^{\infty} $ is Cauchy and thus converges, denote its limit by $$y_n = \lim_{j \to \infty} x_n ^ j $$
> All we have left to do to show completeness is to show that $ y = \{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in \ell^2 $  and that $\lim_{j \to \infty} \left\| y-x^j  \right\| = 0 $. Hint: we are instructed to show that the sequence $\{ \lVert x^j \rVert \} _{j=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy, hence convergent and bounded.

Here is what I have thus far: we can use the reverse triangle inequality $$| \lVert x^j \rVert - \lVert x^k \rVert | \leq \lVert x^j-x^k \rVert $$ which indeed shows that $\{ \lVert x^j \rVert \} _{j=1}^{\infty} $ is a Cauchy, and hence convergent and thus bounded sequence. But I am stuck. I cannot show the two remaining tasks using the given hint.I realize there are references to this but none follow this approach which I am interested in completing using the given instructions. Can somebody please help me formally complete the proof? I thank all helpers.

Comment: The hint is bad. The fact that $\|x^{j}\|$ is  Cauchy is of no use. Try to follows the proof in some other source.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: thank you but I could not find a source that did it completely. All seem to leave the two remaining tasks as an exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n^{j}-x_n^{k}|^{2} <\epsilon$. This implies that each term in the sum is less than $\epsilon$. This means $(x_n^{j})_j$ is  Cauchy sequence of real/complex  numbers for each fixed $n$. Let $x_n$ be the limit of this sequence. Now, if $N$ is any positive integer then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} |x_n^{j}-x_n^{k}|^{2} <\epsilon$. Letting $k \to \infty$ in this we get $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} |x_n^{j}-x_n|^{2} \leq \epsilon$ for $j  >K$. Apply this for  a particular $j$, say $j=K+1$ and conclude from this that $x=(x_n) \in \ell^{2}$. Finally we get $\|x^{j}-x\|^{2} \leq \epsilon$ (by letting $N \to \infty$). This finishes the proof.

Comment: thank you, so there is no need for the hint given?

Comment: @kroner As I said, it is bad, useless hint.

Comment: why can we conclude from $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} |x_n^{j}-x_n|^{2} \leq \epsilon$ that $x=(x_n) \in \ell^{2}$  ?

Comment: Using the fact that $(a+b)^{2} \leq 2(a^{2}+b^{2})$  we get $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}x_n^{2}\leq 2[\epsilon+\|x^{j}\|^{2}]$ where we take $j=K+1$. Now let $N \to \infty$.

Comment: thank you, my sequences are complex, does this hurt your argument?

Comment: @kroner In my answer I did not assume that the sequences are real. But in previous comment I have to replace $x_n^{2}$ by $|x_n|^{2}$ in the complex case. Otherwise there is no problem in the proof fo rthe complex case.

Comment: Hi, I have a question Why can't we just take k to infinity without having a finite sum of  N terms? I am quite confused about the reason why we need the finite sum in there. Thanks